# How to make custom function for spring data jpa to get all records of a class A if A.B.activeInd = true

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to write a custom Spring-Data-JPA function without using *@Query* annotation?

Suppose two classes class A and Class B. Class A has Set of Class B. Class B has a variable activeInd of boolean type.

I need all the records of Class A where **B.activeInd = true.**

```
public Class A{
private Long aId;
private String name;
private Set<B> dataByAid; 
}

public Class B{
private Long bId;
private boolean activeInd;
}
```

I just need all the records for class A including the set of class B where **B.activeInd = true/false**.

Comment: Are both A and B  entities? I guess you could do write the following method in the repository `List<A> findByB_activeInd(Boolean activeInd)`.

Comment: Yes A and B both are entities.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `@Query` annotation? without it the answer is: implement a custom method as described in the reference of Spring Data JPA, inject the `EntityManager` in the implementation and use the query you would normally put in the annotation.